# improperly specified vm option when launching android studio

Tags: java, android

[image]

to speed up android studio i changed some setting which i seen in stackoverflow .
i changed **Help> Edit Custom VM Options** to

```
-Xms1024m 
-Xmx4096m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m 
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=440m 
-XX:+UseCompressedOops 
-XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

after that, when i laucnhing android studio showing this message ....

**what i tried....**

1. reinstlled android studio and java
2. when i check stackoverflow they saying to delete **~/.AndroidStudoio3.1/config/studio64.vmoptions**but there no file like that in my directory....
   is there any other solutions?
   please help me....Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had this exact same problem and navigated to your question in an attempt to find the answer.

You are indeed right that you need to delete ~/.AndroidStudoio3.1/config/studio64.vmoptions. Android Studio stores a config to your user profile which is why the problem persisted after you uninstalled the program file itself. You can find the file you're looking for under **C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1**. Delete studios64.vmoptions and you should be able to launch Android Studio. If you're still trying to optimize your workspace you could try:

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio
-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio
```

sources:
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config
https://riptutorial.com/android-studio/example/11146/customize-the-vm-option

Comment: Thanks a lot , i am so happy one day i stucked on this problem you saved me thanks a lot.......

Comment: and i have one question that if i chage...........-Xms1024m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
.....what is the benefit i tried this like code to boost android studio speed but that causes the "improperly specified vm option" Error ...is this code cause any difficulties ..???

Comment: I changed my studio64.exe.vmoptions file under my Program Files. Though I am not sure if editing this file increased in speed, Android Studios will startup and run with these settings. These are the supposed "optimized settings" that I pulled from https://riptutorial.com/android-studio/example/11146/customize-the-vm-option this site. (I thought I had linked this in the original post; evidently not.) I am not positive what these changes do other than it increases allocated memory and adds a couple of extra properties, sorry.

Comment: Changing the file's contents to the code in your answer didn't work, but deleting the file entirely worked.